# Pylint and python <tool> run clash about relative imports of a package ('No module named <package-name>' error if I do it the pylint way)

Tags: python-2.7, pylint

I already checked if my question was answered elsewhere, but the 2 questions ([Can anyone explain python's relative imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports) and [Python gives relative import error for package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881667/python-gives-relative-import-error-for-package)) I found that looked the most as mine did not answer my problem. I also searched using the following search query: "*no module named package.module*".)

I'm working on a package which should both be usable as tool and be able to be imported by other scripts.
So I set it up in the following way:

```
/<package_name>/__init__.py # to be able to import it by other scripts
               /__main__.py # to be able to use it 'live' as tool
               /<modules.py>
```

Originally I had my `__main__.py` and my modules set up as *pylint* wants:
using a "*mocked*" `__main__.py` as example:

```
import package_name.module1 as module1
import package_name.module2 as module2

def main(arg_list=None):
    module1.somefunction()
    module2.somefunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I execute this I get the following error (even in `__main__.py`):

```
No module named package_name.module1
```

If I remove the `package_name` from the imports the execution work, but then pylint starts complaining:

```
__main__.py: 1: [W0403(relative-import), ] Relative import 'module1', should be 'package_name.module1'
__main__.py: 2: [W0403(relative-import), ] Relative import 'module2', should be 'package_name.module2'
```

I already tried `from package_name import module1` but also then I get the same error when executing the code.

What should I do to fix it so both pylint and the tool execution accept the same code (preferable the import as pylint wants it)?

**Edit**: Just for clarity: the company I'm working for still uses Python 2.7 at the moment, but we are making the code python 3 compatible by using the Python 3 print-statements and such (`from __future__ import <python3 functionality>`).

(Note: `__init__.py` only imports `__main__.py` and calls `main()` and for that no issues are given when I do `import package_name.__main__`)

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understood the current issue fully. The code seems fine to me. Often these kinds of issues boil down to figuring out the right way to call the code. In that case, you might want to make sure that you call it like that: `python -m package_name`, and Python should automatically find and run `package_name/__main__.py`. Is that already how you run the code? Which command do you use to run _pylint_?

Comment: @sinoroc: Put your comment as answer please, since it is the answer.
I've been working to much with normal scripts for the last year, so I did not think about the -m option <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine to me. Often these kinds of issues boil down to figuring out the right way to call the code. In that case, you might want to make sure that you call it like that: `python -m package_name`, and Python should automatically find and run `package_name/__main__.py`.